# Is there the opposite of -append to remove items from a file?

Tags: powershell

I'm reading a list of users in from a file, changing their password, and then writing out 2 files, one with successes and one with failures.

I want to automate this process. I thought about doing a compare once the script is done, but it would be cleaner to simply remove the users from the list when the change is successful. Is there something that works like the opposite to -Append for the out-file function? I'd like to edit the file instead of re-writing the whole thing every time.

Comment: Not really -remember, the files on disk are just long strings of bytes - appending an extra string of bytes is easy, but yanking out a specific portion in the middle of it is not quite so simple. You will have to rewrite/overwrite the whole file. Alternatively, you could use the "success" file as a filter for the input file - next time you run a batch, just keep skipping user entries if they're already found in the success file

Comment: I can use this to do a compare between the 2 files and get a text output of the differences but how would I use the first file as a filter for the second file?
Compare-object (get-content usersremaining.txt) (get-content reseterrors.txt) |Select -ExpandProperty InputObject

Comment: `$existing = Get-Content success_list.txt; $filtered = Get-Content original_list.txt |Where-Object { $existing -notcontains $_ }`

Comment: I'll have to try that. Add that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, "removing a line" from a file is not as trivial as most graphical text editors make it look!

The logical contents of text file on disk is just a continuous string of byte values. Text processors can optimize disk I/O by keeping track of the *lowest offset* modification (ie. the modifications made closest to the top left corner of the editor) and then only writing the remaining part of the text to disk from the corresponding offset in the file - but you can't just "remove a line" in the middle of the file as a file system operation - that would just leave a huge gap in the file data.

Assuming the maximum number of users in question are counted in the hundreds or a few thousands, you don't have to worry about disk performance, just remove the relevant lines in-memory in PowerShell and overwrite the original file with the remaining list:

```
$allUsers = Get-Content .\full_list.txt
$alreadyProcessed = Get-Content .\success.txt

$remainingUsers = $allUsers | Where-Object { $alreadyProcessed -notcontains $_ }

$remainingUsers |Set-Content .\full_list.txt
```